# Project planning, Note taking tool for developers

Tags: project-management, knowledge-management

i am looking for a project planning tool that include features like a organizer, todo list, target * deadlines of projects.

since i am a developer, it will be good to have a tool that can also do modelling like UML/ERD etc.

i am also looking for something that can do note taking. something like a blog with code snipplets - so with syntax highlighting. OneNote etc all does not have code highlighting - the best i can do is use an online syntax highlighter to generate HTML then paste in which is slow.

of course its good to have a free/open source tool that has all the features i listed. but its fine to know what paid options are there

Comment: Maybe this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/78756/what-do-you-use-to-keep-notes-as-a-developer) has the answer.

Comment: 1 of the main features i thought of having in my note taking is code coloring, hmm but like none out there have that ... hmm ... maybe i will use a wiki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally i guess a combination of a blogging tool (joomla/wordpress) with developer related plugins - syntax highlighting - calendar/project management plugin with a wiki will be best for me ... personally at least ...

maybe throw in a bug management app or something like that ... google wave also seems interesting

hope google apps will improve, i think that will be good

Answer (score 2):

Why does it have to be one tool? A combination of Outlook or Evolution (or KDE tools) and a UML tool like Umbrello would be far better than some kind of swiss-army knife jack-of-all-trades program.

The UNIX philosophy is based on the concept of many tools doing specialized tasks. The desktop, the command-line and open standards tie them together. For the most part this works very well.

Frankly i've never had much luck with programs that aim to be everything to everyone. Usually the end result is simply bloated and buggy.

Anyway, for the planner I suggest you look at [Taskcoach](http://www.taskcoach.org/). It's fantastic and has much of what you're looking for.

Comment: i didnt mean for it to be 1 tool, but best if its all integrated of course.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the IDEs like Eclipse offer plugins for many such things.

It has plugins for organizers, UML, todo lists, project deadlines (mylyn).

I am not sure if there is a plugin for taking notes although I have heard there is a blogging plugin available.

**EDIT:** There is a [plugin](http://robrohan.com/2007/02/07/blogging-from-within-eclipse-metaweblog-plugin/) to write blogs from within Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at gmail - google docs - google calendar - I'm starting to think it has all the tools needed for a developer/project manager